# The definitive guide to/of

Tags: articles, gerunds

Which one is correct?

> The definitive guide **to** surviving in...

or

> The definitive guide **of** surviving in...

Also can I say `the definite guide`?

Comment: It's always _a guide to_. _Definite_ doesn't mean the same as _definitive_ - look them up.

Comment: There's many English books that are titled in "a guide of sth" and "a guide for sth"

Comment: Can you supply any examples of "a guide of"? Admittedly "a guide for" is used, but that means 'for a particular type of person', never 'for' the subject.

Comment: It is a pity that Kate Bunting did not post her comments as an answer. They are simple, succinct, and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about which prepositions that the word *guide* (meaning written instructions) licenses for the prepositional phrases that act as a complement. The overwhelming choice is *to*. The google finds 19.6M hits on "definitive guide"; 18.2M of those are for "definitive guide to." That's better than 90% for the *to* case, a large percentage even allowing for the inevitable false drops. However, other prepositions are acceptable. I find the following list of prepositions indicating the topic of the guide:

1. IN
2. ON
3. AS TO
4. OF
5. ABOUT
6. FOR
7. CONCERNING

The following prepositions indicate the audience for the guide:

8. FOR
9. OF

And, of course, the preposition BY indicates the author of the guide.

Examples follow.

**[1]** 
Logic can thus indeed take many clues from language, but can by no means use it as **the definitive guide in** the analysis of thought-processes and for establishing its rules. (*Husserl’s Position in the School of Brentano* by R D Rollinger, 2013, p 312)

**[2]** *Loving the G-Spot: **The Definitive Guide on** the Secret Center of Feminine Pleasure* by M Durante
*Our Invisible Allies: **The Definitive Guide on** Angels and How They Work Behind the Scenes* by R Phillips, 2009

**[3]** Despite its helpfulness as a general framework, the classification of the zones of the neck is by no means **a definitive guide as to** operative or nonoperative management of neck injuries.

**[4]** ***Archaeological Guide of** Kosovo by M Berisha, 2012
***Reference Guide of*** Diagnostics for the Generative Syntax by Koji Arakawa

**[5]** *My First **Pocket Guide About** South Carolina* by C. Marsh, 2011.

**[6]** *How To Cure Tennis Elbow - **The Definitive Guide For** The Treatment of Tennis Elbow* by A Nicholson.

**[7]** ***Antitrust guide concerning*** research joint ventures 
United States Department of Justice, Antitrust Division, 1980.

**[8]** *Dog: **The Definitive Guide for** Dog Owners* by B Fogle, 2011.

**[9]** ***The Guide of*** the Perplexed - Volume 1 by Moses Maimonides, translated by S. Pines, 1963.